# Using java.util.randomUUID for setInsertId and no new data after some time

Tags: google-bigquery

Setting the insertid with randomUUID on row level and after some time, I see that no rows being introduced to big query. I've instrumented the code to capture the failures and even though no failure causing retry, it is not streaming data into big query. One thing perhaps I should mention is that we maintain queue of connections to avoid warm up period and all. I suspect that somehow it is identifying any incoming rows as duplicate!

Populating batch of rows as;
rowList.add(new Rows().setJson(this.row).setInsertId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));

then, calling InsertBatch method;

```
    TableDataInsertAllRequest content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
Throwable cause = null;
try{
    while(retryStrategy.retriesRemaining()){
        try{
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bq.tabledata().insertAll(bqProjectId, DataSetId, TableId, content).execute();

        if (response.getInsertErrors()!=null){
            warn("Inserting One of the rows has failed");
            statsKeeper.post(BigQueryStat.REMOTE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.getId(), 1L);

            throw new SocketTimeoutException();
        }
        else 
            return true;
        } catch(Throwable e){
            cause = e;
            if (!shouldRetry(e, retryStrategy)) {
                statsKeeper.post(BigQueryStat.SERVICE_DOWN_REPORT.getId(), 1L);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!retryStrategy.retriesRemaining())
        statsKeeper.post(BigQueryStat.SERVICE_DOWN_REPORT.getId(), 1L);
} catch(Exception e){
    throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Is there any obvious reason why google bq apis determines those rows as duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the times/tables that you're encountering this behavior on? There is a 1-2 minute warm up period before rows potentially appear, and occasionally rows take longer if the associated backend system encounters some data availability issues.

Comment: Because we maintain queue of bq connections, mostly we can avoid warm up period. The issue occurs when I utilize retry logic, I bounce the service, I see test cases pushing some data then no more data at all. tables are zip_visit or zip_SignIn, the retry was running last night around 6pm. Since it impacted our integration environment, I had to roll back the changes. If you guys prefer to monitor&test it while I run the retry logic, we can do it anytime, just let me know bnemutlu at zulily dot com